# @scheduled annotation in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, scheduled-tasks, scheduler

I have created a scheduled job in spring boot, in which I have also used @schdeulerlock.
The problem is scheduler is not working properly.
If the job is scheduled to execute after every 10 min, so if the process takes more than 10 mins then what will happen, although there is a @schdeulerlock which release lock acter 15 mins

Answer (score 0):

Scheduled task will never run in parallel. It waits for previous invocation to finish before it starts next one

See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49671739/1101512) for more details