# Thread.sleep within @Scheduled method in Spring

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-boot, scheduled-tasks

I have a method that is scheduled to run each X ms.

This method is launching a new method within a new thread.

Nevertheless, I want to delay this method before counting again.

Here is my code:

```
@Scheduled(fixedRate = RATE_IN_MS)
public void myMethod(){
    new Thread(() -> method()).start();
    Thread.sleep(RATE_IN_MS);
}
```

The problem is that the behavior is not like I want.

Here is the current behavior:

1. After RATE_IN_MS myMethod is launched.
2. method() start running in a different thread.
3. After RATE_IN_MS myMethod is launched.

The problem: Why does my sleep method didn't delay the next launch of myMethod? RATE_IN_MS (by fixedDelay) + RATE_IN_MS (because of Thread.sleep(RATE_IN_MS) need to be the real delay between them.

What I'm missing here?

Thanks!

Comment: @ShanuGupta - Why? I am using the same constant RATE_IN_MS. In addition, why they are related each other? even if I would like to sleep for RATE_IN_MS / 2 it needs to be ok.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38842507/what-different-between-fixed-rate-and-fixed-delay-in-schedule-spring

Comment: because, you are running at fixedRate, no matter what happened with your execution, the thread will call your myMethod(). Use fixedDelay instead.

Comment: I understand that, but if sleep time will be `>` than the fixed rate, how it will affect this scenario?

Answer (score 2):

I have created this running example for your reference.Execution delay is configured in spring configuration file which can be changed as you wish.

```
package com.myprgm;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.scheduling.TaskScheduler;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableScheduling;
import org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@EnableScheduling
public class JobSchdulingServc {
    @Value("${com.executionDelay}")
    private long executionDelay; // in milliseconds,mention in sping property file
    @Autowired
    TaskScheduler taskScheduler;

    @Bean
    public TaskScheduler poolScheduler() {
        return new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
    }

    private void stopSceduling(boolean terminateJob) {
        ((ThreadPoolTaskScheduler) taskScheduler).shutdown();
        if (terminateJob) {
            System.exit(1);
        }

    }
    public void scheduleMyJob() {
        taskScheduler.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    someServiceimpl.generateMyDataAndSendInEveryMilliSeconds(); // service you want to execute after
                    // specified executionDelay
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    stopSceduling(true);
                }
            }

        }, executionDelay);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

With `fixedRate`, the scheduler does not care the time spent in `myMethod`.

You can use `@Scheduled(fixedDelay = RATE_IN_MS)`. The scheduler will calculate next execution time after finishing `myMethod`.

Answer (score 0):

When using `fixedrate` scheduling, there are two possible situations as to when the next invocation of `myMethod` occurs:

1. if after `RATE_IN_MS` milliseconds from the last `myMethod` invocation, `myMethod` is no longer running, then that's when `myMethod` will be invoked again.
2. if after `RATE_IN_MS` milliseconds from the last `myMethod` invocation that invocation is still running and it hasn't returned, then this will cause the next scheduled call to be blocked until the current invocation is over.

For example if `RATE_IN_MS` is 10 ms, let's consider two scenarios:

1. `myMethod` takes 5 ms to execute. In this case, a new `myMethod` invocation will occur every 10 ms because 5 ms is less than 10 ms.
2. if for some reason the last `myMethod` invocation took 12 ms to complete, which is longer than 10 ms, then the next one will be queued. So there will be a minimum of 12 ms between invocation which is more than `RATE_IN_MS`.

Now to answer your question specifically, let's say that `RATE_IN_MS` is 10 ms, then definitely we have the second case from my above example, however, the wait time will not be multiplied in two as you expect, rather it will be consisted of two time periods:

1. the time it took `myMethod` to reach `Thread.sleep(RATE_IN_MS)` which could be much less than `RATE_IN_MS`, let's say it's only 3 ms and let's call this time X.
2. the time the Thread sleeps which is `RATE_IN_MS` which we are saying it's 10 ms for example.

Then the total time between invocations of `myMethod()` will be: X+`RATE_IN_MS` which according to my example is 13 ms and not `RATE_IN_MS` * 2.