# Is Spring Boot @Scheduled & multi POD deployment

Tags: sql, spring-boot, scheduler, race-condition, kubernetes-pod

for scheduler job we used @Scheduled at method level like below.

```
@scheduled(fixedRateString = 120)
public void performUpdate(){
}
```

Since I am also using the multi POD deployment it will cause RACE condition I guess because from each POD, same request will go to each POD & perform SQL update & delete operations.

Comment: It will wait, some details here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38842507/whats-the-difference-between-fixed-rate-and-fixed-delay-in-spring-scheduled-ann