# What is the expected behaviour of spring @scheduled cron when jobs would overlap?

Tags: java, spring, cron

I have a job that runs once an hour, and I'm using Spring's @scheduled cron to schedule it.

If the job takes more than an hour, I understand from [How to prevent overlapping schedules in Spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24033208/how-to-prevent-overlapping-schedules-in-spring) that the next job won't kick off while the first job is running.

But does this mean that it WILL kick off after the first job has completed, or has it missed its chance?

If I have one job that takes 10 hours, will all the missed cron jobs queue up and then execute one by one when the first job completes after 10 hours, or will just the first job run?

Thanks!

Comment: cronjoby are executed in separate threads. So when its time, a new thread is spawned and executed irrespective of previous execution is compete or not. (if you use fixeddelay, then it waits for completion of previously running task)

Comment: @pvpkiran Your comment is incorrect. spring scheduled cron jobs will not kick off if a previous iteration is running, regardless of what executor you have - please see the second answer in the answer I linked.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21993464/does-spring-scheduled-annotated-methods-runs-on-different-threads

Comment: I believe that the example in Igor's answer contradicts your assertion that "cronjobs are executed in separate threads. So when its time, a new thread is spawned and executed irrespective of previous execution is compete or not." The numbers are returned in sequence which does not fit with your model.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

By default, execution is blocking and single-threaded, which means they will not run concurrently. If you want jobs to run simultaneously, you can annotate the method as `@Async` as well.  You may also want to look at the different [`Executors`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html).

If you're using `fixedDelay` like in the sample question you provided, the next job will only kick off AFTER the current one is over, plus the delay.  So if your job takes 10 hours and you have a `fixedDelay` of `5000`, the next job will kick off 5 seconds after the 10 hour one.

If you're using `fixedRate` then the next scheduled event will be queued up to run, but not skipped, as per the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html#scheduleAtFixedRate-java.lang.Runnable-long-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-):

> If any execution of this task takes longer than its period, then
>   subsequent executions may start late, but will not concurrently
>   execute.

If you are simply using `cron`, then the jobs will be queued and executed in turn (similar to `fixedRate`).  You can test this with a simple method (below is in Groovy, but can use plain Java too):

```
    int i = 0

    @Scheduled(cron = '* * * * * * ')
    void test() {
        if (i < 5)
            Thread.sleep(10000)

        i += 1
        println '------------------------' + i // No values skipped
    }
```

You'll note that every number is printed; e.g. no cycle is ever skipped.

Comment: Thanks - but you haven't answered my question.

Comment: @Bruce Updated.  Without code it was a little ambiguous as I thought you were asking about fixedDelay's/fixedRate's interaction w/cron.

Comment: Ah ok thanks - your edit does answer the question. Thanks!

Comment: The answer below https://stackoverflow.com/a/56889523/1527469 seems to contradict the cron scenario, when it says "jobs are NOT queued"--which doesn't in itself imply whether the next counter is incremented it is, but according to that answer there's no possibility of a memory leak in some queue, if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 15):

The behaviour of `fixedRate` and `cron` is different.

Overlapping jobs are queued for `fixedRate` (as per the above answer from @Igor).

Overlapping jobs are skipped for `cron`.

Sample Java code to demonstrate the difference:

```
int i = 0;
@Scheduled(fixedRate = 5000)
public void test() throws InterruptedException {
    Date start = new Date();
    if (i < 3) Thread.sleep(10000);
    i++;
    System.out.printf("start %TT, finish %TT, i = %s%n", start, new Date(), i);
}
```

And the output:

```
start 13:25:30, finish 13:25:40, i = 1
start 13:25:40, finish 13:25:50, i = 2
start 13:25:50, finish 13:26:00, i = 3
start 13:26:00, finish 13:26:00, i = 4
start 13:26:00, finish 13:26:00, i = 5
start 13:26:00, finish 13:26:00, i = 6
start 13:26:00, finish 13:26:00, i = 7
start 13:26:05, finish 13:26:05, i = 8
start 13:26:10, finish 13:26:10, i = 9
start 13:26:15, finish 13:26:15, i = 10
```

As can be seen, the overlapping jobs are queued and start as soon as the previous one completes, with no 5 second gap.

However, if we use `@Scheduled(cron = "*/5 * * ? * *")` instead, the output becomes:

```
start 13:22:10, finish 13:22:20, i = 1
start 13:22:25, finish 13:22:35, i = 2
start 13:22:40, finish 13:22:50, i = 3
start 13:22:55, finish 13:22:55, i = 4
start 13:23:00, finish 13:23:00, i = 5
start 13:23:05, finish 13:23:05, i = 6
start 13:23:10, finish 13:23:10, i = 7
start 13:23:15, finish 13:23:15, i = 8
start 13:23:20, finish 13:23:20, i = 9
start 13:23:25, finish 13:23:25, i = 10
```

There is always a 5 second gap between the jobs. The overlapping jobs are NOT queued and are skipped.

Answer (score 2):

Overlapping jobs are queued for **fixedRate** and they are skipped for **cron** as mentioned by @firstmanonmars

If we want to execute the corn schedulers overlapping to each other without waiting, we can use **@Async** and **@EnableAsync** as shown below.

```
@EnableScheduling
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAsync

public class TaskSchedulerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TaskSchedulerApplication.class, args);
    }
    
    @Bean
    public TaskScheduler taskScheduler() {
        final ThreadPoolTaskScheduler scheduler = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
        scheduler.setPoolSize(10);
        return scheduler;
    }
}
```

**Scheduler Demo:**

```
@Component
public class DemoScheduler {
    
    @Async
    @Scheduled(cron = "*/5 * * * * MON-FRI")
    public void startJob() {
        System.out.println(String.format("%s - Thread name - %s ",new Date(), Thread.currentThread().getName()));
        sleep(6000);
    }

    private void sleep(int millis) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(millis);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Running the code gives the following output which shows that they are running by multiple threads in parallel in an interval of 5 sec:**

```
Thu May 06 09:59:05 IST 2021 - Thread name - task-1 
Thu May 06 09:59:10 IST 2021 - Thread name - task-2 
Thu May 06 09:59:15 IST 2021 - Thread name - task-3 
Thu May 06 09:59:20 IST 2021 - Thread name - task-4 
Thu May 06 09:59:25 IST 2021 - Thread name - task-5 
Thu May 06 09:59:30 IST 2021 - Thread name - task-6 
Thu May 06 09:59:35 IST 2021 - Thread name - task-7 
Thu May 06 09:59:40 IST 2021 - Thread name - task-8 
Thu May 06 09:59:45 IST 2021 - Thread name - task-1 
Thu May 06 09:59:50 IST 2021 - Thread name - task-2 
Thu May 06 09:59:55 IST 2021 - Thread name - task-3
```

Comment: This is not an answer, therefore more suited to be a comment. Please review the SO guidelines.

Comment: Thanks, I have improved the answer including an example.