# Spring @Scheduled, how to run once at time (not concurrently)

Tags: spring, spring-scheduled

I have an annotated method width `@Scheduled` with an `cron` of `*/15 * * * * ?` (run each 15 seconds).

Sometimes this process take more than 15 seconds to run.

Is there any way to avoid the call of the `@Scheduled` if it's already running?

My workaround currently is a flag field in the class to signal if the process is running, and if it is marked the code exits before execute the main code.

Answer (score 3):

I think it's already the case, if the first job has'nt finished, the second will not start.

See :
[How to prevent overlapping schedules in Spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24033208/how-to-prevent-overlapping-schedules-in-spring)

If it isn't working, you can also use an AtomicBoolean to check if you must start the process or not.